# Switching from Front to Back Camera : Multiple audio/video AVCaptureInputs are not currently supported

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, camera

I am trying to switching Camera from Front to Back and vice versa. But the code giving exception " Multiple audio/video AVCaptureInputs are not currently supported" and my app get crashed randomly.

```
func addVideoInput() {
    let device: AVCaptureDevice = self.deviceWithMediaTypeWithPosition(AVMediaTypeVideo, position: AVCaptureDevicePosition.Front)
    do {
        let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)
        if self.session.canAddInput(input) {
            self.session.removeInput(input)
            if session.inputs.isEmpty {
                self.session.addInput(input)
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
```

**Calling method on backButton click**

```
func initilizeBackCamera() -> Bool {

    var success  = false

    let device: AVCaptureDevice = (self.deviceWithMediaTypeWithPosition(AVMediaTypeVideo, position: AVCaptureDevicePosition.Back))
    do {
        let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)
         self.session.removeInput(input)
        if session.canAddInput(input) {
            if self.session.inputs.isEmpty {
              self.session.addInput(input)
                success = true
            }
        }

    } catch {

        print(error)
        success = false
    }

    return success;
}
```

**Calling method on frobtButton click**

```
 func initilizeFrontCamera() -> Bool {

    var success  = false
    let device: AVCaptureDevice = (self.deviceWithMediaTypeWithPosition(AVMediaTypeVideo, position: AVCaptureDevicePosition.Front))
    do {
        let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)

         self.session.removeInput(input)
        if session.canAddInput(input) {
            if self.session.inputs.isEmpty {
                self.session.addInput(input)
                success = true
            }

        }

    } catch {

        print(error)
         success = false
    }
     return success;
}
```

Comment: Maybe the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35361519/swift-avcapturesession-close-open-button-error-multiple-audio-video-avcapturei

Comment: Yeah .! Thanks..  I have already tried that you are suggesting me as you can see in my code but I am still getting the same issue..

Comment: You need to remove all the inputs before adding a new input device, you are not checking it. you are just adding inputs again and again.. Just place this piece of code in the start of function if `let inputs = captureSession.inputs as? [AVCaptureDeviceInput] {
    for input in inputs {
        captureSession.removeInput(input)
    }
}`

Comment: Hey..! Thank you. it's working now.